# Accessing shared data from a worker thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, mfc, thread-safety

I have the following code:

```
void COrganizerProgressDlg::LaunchWorkerThread()
{
    CWorkerData data;
    data.m_pWndOrganizerProgressDlg = this;
    data.m_pWndImageOrganizerDlg = m_pWndImageOrganizerDlg;
    ::AfxBeginThread(RunBackgroundWorker, &data);
}
```

And here is my `RunBackgroundWorker()` method, which is a `static` method.

```
UINT COrganizerProgressDlg::RunBackgroundWorker(LPVOID pParam)
{
    try
    {
        // Run organizer engine
        COrganizerEngine engine(m_nNotifyMessage, (CWorkerData*)pParam);
        engine.Run();
    }
    catch (CException *e)
    {
        e->ReportError();
        e->Delete();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The data is being used to initialize settings in my worker class.

The problem is that my `data` variable contains valid data before calling `AfxBeginThread()`, but seems to contain garbage within `RunBackgroundWorker()`.

What am I missing? How can I access this data from my worker thread?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`data` is an object with automatic storage duration. Once it goes out of scope, it is no longer valid. I'm assuming, that `data` goes out of scope before the worker thread gets a chance to pick up the information.

To solve this there are essentially 2 options:

- Create a synchronization object (e.g. a [CEvent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/efk30beh.aspx)), and have the worker thread signal it, when it is done reading the data. Call [WaitForSingleObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687032.aspx) in the main thread to block execution until that happens. This is subject to deadlocks, e.g. when the worker thread dies.
- An easier solution is to use dynamic memory management. Use `new` to allocate a `CWorkerData` instance and pass the address to the worker thread. The worker thread can then call `delete`, whenever its done with the object.

Comment: D'oh! Forgot about the automatic storage duration here. Thanks for getting me back on track. I've been using `CEvent` but am not yet very comfortable with it. Think perhaps I should read more about that.

Comment: @JonathanWood: Using a synchronization object is more involved, and it is only applicable, if the worker thread doesn't need the information throughout it's lifetime. The code you posted looks like this is not the case. I'd go with the second option, and transfer ownership of the data altogether. The worker thread can decide, when it's time to clean up.

Comment: Yes, I did. I copied some code though that used `CEvent` to handle the user cancelling the operation. Just seemed like I should probably understand that a little better.